# How do I center UILabel TEXT horizontally?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

Now I've seen a lot of examples that teach you either how to center the UILabel Text in the middle of the screen, but that's not what I'm asking for. I'm asking on how to make sure that the text of UILabel remains half way between the left and right bounds of the screen and All I have to do is make adjustments Vertically. I have the following:

```
self.aboutMee = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 120, self.view.bounds.size.width)];
            self.aboutMee.text = @"About Me";
            self.aboutMee.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            self.aboutMee.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            self.aboutMee.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
            [self.aboutMee setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:140.0/255.0 blue:199.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
            [self.aboutMee setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLTStd-ThCn" size:35]];
            [self.scrollView addSubview:self.aboutMee];
```

Now I've tried to make the entire label 320 in width and then just center the text, but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: can you just build it in interface builder? you can pin views to the center using NSLayoutContraints; very easy to do in IB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should set frame correctly:   CGRectMake(pos.x, pos.y, width, height)

```
self.aboutMee = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
        self.aboutMee.text = @"About Me";
        self.aboutMee.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.aboutMee.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.aboutMee.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
        [self.aboutMee setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:140.0/255.0 blue:199.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        [self.aboutMee setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLTStd-ThCn" size:35]];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.aboutMee];
```

Comment: Oh geez. I can't believe I missed that! Thank you, Guntis!